# Does Python[3.6+] built-in Dictionary have any function similar to OrderedDict's move_to_end()

Tags: python, dictionary, lru, ordereddict

I was looking at the solution for LRU cache implementation on leetcode. And the built-in dict is also ordered from Python 3.6+.
I was wondering if there is any function similar to OrderedDict's move_to_end() which I can use with built-in dict and get rid of OrderedDict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class LRUCache(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        """
        :type capacity: int
        """
        self.capacity = capacity

    def get(self, key):
        """
        :type key: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if key not in self:
            return - 1
        
        self.move_to_end(key)
        return self[key]

    def put(self, key, value):
        """
        :type key: int
        :type value: int
        :rtype: void
        """
        if key in self:
            self.move_to_end(key)
        self[key] = value
        if len(self) > self.capacity:
            self.popitem(last = False)
```

Answer (score -1):

The best you can do is remove the entry and reinsert it:

```
d[key] = d.pop(key)
```

Note that there is no efficient way to move an entry to the *start* the way `OrderedDict` supports, due to differences in how order preservation is implemented.